# unexpected output in C (recursion)

Tags: c, recursion

```
int main(void) {
 static int=5;
 if(--i) {
    main();
    printf("%d",i);
   }
 }
```

the output of above program is---

0000

But I think it should be---

1234

I dont know why?please help me.

Comment: I think you mean to say `4321`, and it would be if you printed *before* you recursed.

Comment: `static int i=5;` or is there some C-magic that sets `i` to 5?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the zeros is that `i` is decremented down to zero before the very first `printf` statement is run.  As it unwinds, it prints i (which is still zero) each time.

It would be better to use a separate function that `main()` calls and passes a parameter to (and then pass the parameter to each call rather than using a static variable).

Answer (score 2):

1. You set a static variable `i` to 5
2. You recurse on `main` until `i` becomes zero.
3. The recursion unwinds with `i` being zero.
4. This then calls the `printf`

There lies the answer.

You can prove this by using a debugger

Answer (score -1):

```
  [First call:  i->4 and call main()]
  [Second call: i->3 and call main()]
  [Third call:  i->2 and call main()]
  [Fourth call: i->1 and call main()]
  [Fifth call:  i->0 and condition false as it gives 0.]
```

Now it's time for the printing of value of i, which was the next line after main(). Control go back to fourth to first call to print value of i.

```
[Fourth Call: printing value of i which is 0.]
[Third call:  printing value of i which is 0.]
[Second call: printing value of i which is 0.]
[First call:  printing value of i which is 0.]
```